# Regex to validate a comma separated list of unique email addresses

Tags: regex

I need help troubleshooting a regex pattern. To validate a comma delimited list of unique email addresses I have this regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8igywV/1/)):

```
^
(?!.*(\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})\b).*\b\1\b)
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})
(?:,(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}))*
$
```

This regex rightly matches these:

```
test@foo.com,test1@foo.com
test.email@foo.com,test.email1@foo.com
test.email@foo.com,test.email1@foo.com,test.email2@foo.com
```

But fails to match these (while it should):

```
test.email@foo.com,test1.email@foo.com
test.email@foo.com,test+email@foo.com
test-email@foo.com,test+email@foo.com
test-email@foo.com,test%email@foo.com
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? when you say validate comma delimited list of emails. Do you want to match what all the email addresses ?

Comment: @rootkonda i expect the regex to match the second set of emails also just it does for the first. each line in the second set is a comma separated string of unique email addresses but somehow the regex fails to match those.

Comment: ^(?:(?:[\w.\-%\+]+@[\w]+\.[\w]+),?)+$ - check this out -https://regex101.com/r/8igywV/3

Comment: @rootkonda yours is short and nice but it allows duplicates

Comment: Do you want to skip the entire line if there is even one duplicate email address in that line ?

Comment: @rootkonda, to make it more clear each line is an independent test string. so i like to  validate each line independently so essentially the expression should work line by line and not on all the lines as a whole (not multiline).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219343/discussion-between-rootkonda-and-manish-surolia).

Comment: could you please try one of these two - `^(?!.*((?:(?<![\w.\-+%])[\w._%+-]+@[\w.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,})).*\1).*$
` and also `^(?!.*(\b(?:(?<![\w.\-+%])[\w._%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})\b).*\1).*$`

Comment: Did you get a chance to test the combinations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments and chat: we have to use negative lookbehind expression(`(?<![\w.\-+%])`) while checking entire string for duplicate email address.

```
^(?!.*((?:(?<![\w.\-+%])[\w._%+-]+@[\w.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)).*\b\1\b)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})(?:,(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}))*$
```